# How to use a SOQL query for Sobjects like Passing Sobject as Variable inside the quey

Tags: soql, dynamic-soql, schema

I'm trying to write a SOQL query, But this query have to work for all object in one query. I want to use same query but I want to change object name dynamically

```
public class Test {
 public static void testme(object obj){
    string query='select name';
    query=query+'from\''+obj+'\'';
    query=query+'limt 1';
    system.debug('query===='+query);
    list<sobject> accounts=database.query(query);
 }
}
```

But it's throwing an error. In this requirement I can pass object api name as parameter. I'm geeting all sobjects through schema.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, you simply need the API name of the object. What is the value of obj?

Comment: Also, you wouldn't need quotes before the object name.

Comment: Any object...For ex Account. Either if I remove quotes or if I keep it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
public class Test {
 public static void testme(String obj){
    string query = 'select name ';
    query=query + ' from ' + obj ;
    query=query + ' limit 1';
    system.debug('query===='+query);
    list<sobject> accounts=database.query(query);
 }
}
```

Take note of spaces in strings.

Comment: System.QueryException: unexpected token: 'Account'

It's throwing an error.

Comment: Above code should work. Can you share how you are calling the method.